# Send email if task failed

Tags: bash, shell, task

I'm writing a shell script that creates a log file of all the tasks it completed. At the very end of the script it creates a tar file and restarts a service.

I would like the script to send an email if the tar process failed or if the service didn't start back up. I'm not sure how to check if the tar and service passed/failed.

Here's an example of the shell script without checking if the tar or service completed...

```
#!/bin/bash

# Shutdown service
service $SERVICE stop

# Task 1
command > some1.log

# Task 2
command > some2.log

# Task 3
command > some3.log

# Compress Tar file
tar -czf logfiles.tar.gz *.log

# Start service
service $SERVICE start

# mail if failed
mail -s "Task failed" | user@domain.com << "the task failed"
```

Update: The script should not abort as I want the service to attempt to start again if any of the prior tasks did fail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check the [exit status](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) produced by each step, and send the mail of any of those exit status raises a flag.

```
# Compress Tar file
tar -czf logfiles.tar.gz *.log

TAR_EXIT_STATUS=$?

# Start service
service $SERVICE start

SERVICE_EXIT_STATUS=$?

# mail if failed
if [ $TAR_EXIT_STATUS -ne 0 ] || [ $SERVICE_EXIT_STATUS -ne 0 ];then
    mail -s "Task failed" | user@domain.com << "the task failed"
fi;
```

Comment: Awesome! This should work. I'm assuming the if statement would use SERVICE_EXIST_STATUS and TAR_EXIT_STATUS ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple solution using a function:

```
#!/bin/bash

failfunction()
{
    if [ "$1" != 0 ]
    then echo "One of the commands has failed!!"
         #mail -s "Task failed" | user@domain.com << "the task failed"
         exit
    fi
}

# Shutdown service
service $SERVICE stop 
failfunction "$?"

# Task 1
command > some1.log 
failfunction "$?"

# Task 2
command > some2.log 
failfunction "$?"

# Task 3
command > some3.log 
failfunction "$?"

# Compress Tar file
tar -czf logfiles.tar.gz *.log 
failfunction "$?"

# Start service
service $SERVICE start 
failfunction "$?"
```

Comment: This would produce too many emails if more than one task failed.

Comment: The `exit` prevents that.

Comment: @user1052448, the difference between this implementation and the one I provided is that this one will abort the script when any of the commands fail, while mine will execute all commands and at the end check if any of the last two failed. You should choose what behaviour you want for your script.

Comment: @none sorry I missed the exit.

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo I prefer to not abort the script - reason being, if the backup fails, I still want the service to attempt to start running again. I updated my question to specify that.